# Go Mux Middlware not using my CORS handler

Tags: go, cors, mux

```
mx := mux.NewRouter()

mx.Use(CorsHandler)


sch := mx.NewRoute().Subrouter()
sch.Use(middleware.ValidateSchoolToken)

teacher := mx.NewRoute().Subrouter()
teacher.Use(middleware.ValidateToken)
```

CorsHandler is not used when the code runs

Comment: Hello @nator welcome to SO, could you describe the error that you are getting? The other thing, that could help your question, is to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Describe the error that you have. And explain your problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `http.MethodOptions` to your Methods call? I found this sample in the documentation:

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    // IMPORTANT: you must specify an OPTIONS method matcher for the middleware to set CORS headers
    r.HandleFunc("/foo", fooHandler).Methods(http.MethodGet, http.MethodPut, http.MethodPatch, http.MethodOptions)
    r.Use(mux.CORSMethodMiddleware(r))
    
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

Full docs: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/mux#readme-handling-cors-requests